# Status 201 in fetch

Tags: javascript

I've the below JS code, that is returning [status 201](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201),
[image]

I'm working it with a local server, that is working correctly once I checked it at [thunder client](https://www.thunderclient.io/) as shown:

[image]

My code is:

```
async function send(params) {
    var path = document.querySelector('#path');
    var skills = document.querySelector('#skills');
    var skillsList = skills.value
    skillsList = skillsList.replace(/\n\r?/g, '|');
    const dataToSend = JSON.stringify({"path": path.value, "skills": skillsList});
    console.log(dataToSend);
    let dataReceived = ""; 
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/getSkills", {
        credentials: "same-origin",
        mode: "cors",
        method: "post",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: dataToSend
    }).then(resp => {
        if (resp.status === 200) {
            return resp.json();
        } else {
            console.log("Status: " + resp.status)
            return Promise.reject("server")
        }
    }).then(dataJson => {
        dataReceived = JSON.parse(dataJson)
        console.log(`Received: ${dataReceived}`)
    }).catch(err => {
        if (err === "server") return
        console.log(err)
    }) 
}
```

Why I'm getting 201, not the returned JSON object as expected, and as shown at thunder client?

Comment: What's your _question_?

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why I'm getting 201, not the returned JSON object as expected, and as shown at thunder client?

Comment: @Furman Why I'm getting 201, not the returned JSON object as expected, and as shown at thunder client?

Comment: Your client says you get a 201 on a success, why does your code say a 201 is a failure?

Comment: Why is your backend returning 201 when you apparently  don’t want that?

Comment: [The HTTP 201 Created success status response code indicates that the request has succeeded and has led to the creation of a resource. The new resource is effectively created before this response is sent back and the new resource is returned in the body of the message, its location being either the URL of the request, or the content of the Location header.

The common use case of this status code is as the result of a POST request.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201)

Comment: @samathingamajig that probably should be an answer or or this question should be flagged as a duplicate

Comment: @Samathingamajig I read it, but did not understand it :(

Comment: _"not the returned JSON"_ you are getting the json as well, you just don't parse it. Your backend is just sending a `201` instead of `200`, if you don't want it doing that then make sure you change your backend to reply properly.

Comment: Every status code that starts with 2 is a success code. Your code _only_ treats 200 as success, but that's probably wrong.

Comment: You explicitly logged that status, because it wasn't 200, why didn't you expected to see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "thunder client" shows that a 201 response code is a success from your backend (and 2xx codes are Successful Responses according to the HTTP standard)

[image: 201 picture]

You explicitly state that if it's not a 200, it's a failure. Change this in your code to accept all 2xx. (window.fetch returns a Response instance, which sets the readonly attribute `ok` to true if the response code is 2xx [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok))

```js
.then(resp => {
  if (resp.ok) {
    return resp.json();
  } else {
    console.log("Status: " + resp.status)
    return Promise.reject("server")
  }
})
```

201 means Created,

> The request has succeeded and a new resource has been created as a result. This is typically the response sent after POST requests, or some PUT requests. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#successful_responses)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just fixed it in my server, replaced `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)` by `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)` appreciate your explanation it guided me to review my server code.